# What are my options for frequent travel between Barcelona and Mataró?

Tags: trains, spain, barcelona

I will regularly take a train from Barcelona to Mataró and back (twice a day, every weekday, starting from October). The R1 line seems to be exactly what I want: [it crosses Barcelona](https://moovitapp.com/index/en/public_transit-line-R1-Barcelona-362-10269-177864-3) with stops in 5 stations in Barcelona itself and it seems to be a very frequent train as well with [a frequency of 6 minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R1%E2%80%93RG1_(Rodalies_de_Catalunya)) during rush hour.

- Where can I find a more detailed timetable?
- What are my options in terms of perhaps a subscription? I will be staying in Barcelona for about 3 months and I'll need transport to Mataró every workday.

Some perhaps useful notes:

- I am a EU citizen.
- I will be in Barcelona supported by the Erasmus program but not with a school (plain old internship).
- I am a student in Belgium.

Answer (score 11):

Using the resource as provided by @pnuts, I have found the following answers to my questions.

### Train schedule

A detailed schedule of the train can be found [here](http://rodalies.gencat.cat/web/.content/pdf/horaris/r1.pdf). For example for the morning commute, these are my likely leave- and arrival-times:

[image]

### Ticket choice

There is a lot of valuable and clear information available [here](http://www.mapametrobarcelona.net/en-precio-metro-barcelona.php). What it boiled down for me is the [T-Jove card](http://www.tmb.cat/en/sistema-tarifari-integrat/-/ticket/TJove). As explained by the official website:

> A personalised travel card valid for an unlimited number of journeys in 90 consecutive days from the first validation for under 25s providing proof of age by means of a valid national ID document, foreigner ID document (NIE) or passport. The number of the ID document must be printed on the travel card.

With points of sale at

> - TMB bus and metro automatic vending machines
> - TMB customer service and information centres (Punt TMB)
> - Other Integrated Fare System operators (stations)
> - Servicaixa
> - Other operators' information centres

After reading through the options what each means, consider using [the Ticket Calculator](http://www.mapametrobarcelona.net/en-calcula-billete-mensual.php) though when I used it it seemed rather broken (according to the calculator, most of the trips I'd take would be around €50/trip).

Very important/useful is the pricetable which gives you an idea of how often, for how long and how far you can go with each ticket.

[image]

In order to accurately find out how many zones you're using, you can use below image:

[image]

Mataró is in zone 3E so I have to account for 3 zones: 1, 2 and 3. Using the above table then tells me the T-Jove card is best (3 months, unlimited trips and 3 zones for €210).

This will differ based on your age, your length of stay, your nationality, your disabilities, etc.

Also an important note:

> ### Which means of public transportation can I use with the tickets?
>
> During a given time, a ticket can be used for the following forms of public transportation, if changing is necessary. The same ticket may be used again, without the machine "chopper" marking a new journey:
>
> - Metro.
> - Bus
> - Train (Renfe).
> - Catalan railway train (FGC).
> - Cable car (Funicular of Montjuïc) in Parallel stop, line 2, the color purple line.
> - Tram.